# UIToolbar setBackgroundColor doesn't fully change color

Tags: ios7, uitoolbar

I'm trying to set the background color of a `UIToolBar`.
I tried selecting the color from IB's Attribute Inspector, and tried setting it programmatically through `setBackgroundColor:[UIColor ...]`.

Both solutions work, but only partially: the color blends something like 50% with white and the toolbar is very light...doesn't show the color I actually chose, but a much lighter version of it.

How can I have the `UIToolBar` of the actual color I'm choosing?
It's probably very simple to solve, but I can't find a way and can't find answers online either.

Answer (score 106, accepted):

Write below code in your `viewDidLoad`

```
self.navigationController.toolbar.barTintColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

It will set red color as your tool bar background.

`Reference link` https://web.archive.org/web/20160321155823/https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TransitionGuide/Bars.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013174-CH8-SW5

In it they said that `Use barTintColor to tint the bar background`.
[image]

Comment: Ah yes, I just tried and works! Can't believe i haven't seen this when i was searching earlier. Thanks a lot.

Comment: sorry, further question... I'm trying now with a more specific color, building it with UIColor colorWithRed:green:blue:alpha: but the color again doesn't show up properly.. this time basically keeps the same hue but drops saturation and brightness of about 25%, here is a picture with it: ![image](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B4pmO_xiSW_4SjQ1N0xBeGpFUG8/edit?usp=sharing)

in the picture you see the left color is the one i want, the right one how it becomes actually. do you have any idea of what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Sorry, for late reply i was busy, i dont have any idea but, i will check it when get free. and if you got solution let me know k ?

Comment: Thank you! I spent way too much time on this one trying to figure out what would let me change the background color.

Comment: @BkdD did you manage to change using colorWithRed:green:blue:alpha? it only works for certain values for me. Very weird behavior

Comment: If only I'd read this two hours ago. Someone give that guy a taco

Comment: Why does .backgroundColor even exist for toolbars then?

Comment: I did not remember but i think it is for supporting older version i.e before ios 7

Comment: you must also set translucent to false

Answer (score 27):

IN iOS 7 you need to set the **barTintColor** Property-

```
UIToolbar *doneToolbar=[[UIToolbar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 584, 320, 44)];
doneToolbar.translucent=NO;
doneToolbar.barTintColor=[UIColor redColor];
[self.view addSubview:doneToolbar];
```

I have used it its working fine...

Answer (score 6):

In addition to Jageen's answer, you must also set the translucent property to false. Otherwise the color will have slightly less saturation and hue than what is specified with barTintColor.

```
// Sets to a specific color
self.navigationController.toolbar.barTintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:6.0 / 255.0 green:52.0 / 255.0 blue:90.0 / 255.0 alpha:1.0];

// Without this, color will be faded slightly and not exactly what's specified above  
self.navigationController.toolbar.translucent = false;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this on IOS 10:

```
let dummyToolbar = UIToolbar()
dummyToolbar.barTintColor = .lightGray
dummyToolbar.sizeToFit() // without this line it doesn't work
```

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 4+:**

```
toolBar.barTintColor = UIColor(red: 92/255, green: 216/255, blue: 255/255, alpha: 1)
toolBar.isTranslucent = false
toolBar.sizeToFit()
```

Answer (score 0):

UIToolbar* numberToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 50)];

> numberToolbar.backgroundcolor = [UIColor redcolor];
>       numberToolbar.items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
>                            [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Clear" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
>   nil];

```
[numberToolbar sizeToFit];
numberTextField.inputAccessoryView = numberToolbar;
```

Answer (score 0):

Throughout App:

```
    UIToolbar.appearance().barTintColor = TOOLBAR_BACKGROUND_COLOR

if let font = UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-DemiBold", size: 15) {
        UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: font,NSForegroundColorAttributeName:TOOLBAR_TITLE_COLOR], forState: UIControlState.Normal)

    }
```