# UIToolbar background colour is not changing

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am using the below code to display a toolbar as a accessory view for a picker view. I want to customise the tool bar colour. I am not sure whats wrong in this below code. Is there a better way to achieve this

```
UIToolbar* state_close = [[UIToolbar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 50)];
state_close.translucent =NO; //.barStyle = UIBarStyleDefault;
state_close.barTintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.94 green:0.94 blue:0.94 alpha:1.0];
[state_close sizeToFit];
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UIToolbar setBackgroundColor doesn't fully change color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19401507/uitoolbar-setbackgroundcolor-doesnt-fully-change-color)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Objective - C

Your code is working fine.
try to change `y` position of the `state_close` like below

```
UIToolbar *state_close = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 200, self.view.frame.size.width, 50)];
state_close.barTintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
state_close.alpha = 1.0;
[state_close sizeToFit];
[self.view addSubview:state_close];
```

if you want to set `y = 0` then hide navigationBar.

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setHidden:true];
```